# Database and API Website On Same Server

Tags: database, api, networking

Should I host an API website with no user interface on the same server the database it's going to read data from?  This would be on a Windows Server 2008 box with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: IMO - Need a lot more info before anyone could give a real answer on that.  The OS for one thing, would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of traffic, there's no problem at all with this setup.

When your server loads increase, you can start having multiple API front end servers connecting to a dedicated DB server.

Just remember to keep connection info centralized and easily configurable (i.e. no hard coded DB host or user in your code). This will make migration much much easier.